# Need to place two stack charts side by side sharing single configuration settings

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts and need to place two stacked bar charts side by side and sharing common download settings. Is their any solution in highcharts? Any examples will be appreciated. Thanks

[Stacked bar - sidebyside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WY9p.png)

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by adding custom logic to `getSVG` method to download multiple charts in one document. To create one shared legend simply use Hicharts API to control series visibility. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
/**
 * Create a global getSVG method that takes an array of charts as an
 * argument
 */
Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts) {
  let svgArr = [],
    top = 0,
    width = 0;

  Highcharts.each(charts, function(chart) {
    let svg = chart.getSVG(),
      // Get width/height of SVG for export
      svgWidth = +svg.match(
        /^<svg[^>]*width\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
      )[1],
      svgHeight = +svg.match(
        /^<svg[^>]*height\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
      )[1];

    svg = svg.replace(
      '<svg',
      '<g transform="translate('+width+', 0 )" '
    );
    svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

    width += svgWidth;
  top = Math.max(top, svgHeight);
 
    svgArr.push(svg);
  });

  return '<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width +
    '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
    svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
};

/**
 * Create a global exportCharts method that takes an array of charts as an
 * argument, and exporting options as the second argument
 */
Highcharts.exportCharts = function(charts, options) {

  // Merge the options
  options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

  // Post to export server
  Highcharts.post(options.url, {
    filename: options.filename || 'chart',
    type: options.type,
    width: options.width,
    svg: Highcharts.getSVG(charts)
  });
};

const chart1 = Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  exporting: {
   enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    id: 'series1',
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      571,
      696,
      970,
      119,
      137,
      154
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'series2',
    data: [
      234,
      123,
      444,
      322,
      543,
      657
    ]
  }],
});

const chart2 = Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
   enabled: false
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    id: 'series1',
    data: [
      139,
      225,
      271,
      196,
      770,
      219,
      537,
      254
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'series2',
    data: [
      214,
      223,
      484,
      122,
      443,
      957
    ]
  }],
});

$('.jsLegendItem').on('click', function(e) {
  const btn = $(this),
    seriesId = this.dataset.name;

  if (!btn.hasClass('legend__item--disabled')) {
    btn.addClass('legend__item--disabled')
  } else {
    btn.removeClass('legend__item--disabled')
  }

  Highcharts.charts.forEach(chart => {
    let series = chart.get(seriesId);

    if (series.visible) {
      series.hide();
    } else {
      series.show();
    }
  });
});

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
 Highcharts.exportCharts([chart1, chart2]);
});
```

```css
#container {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#container1 {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}

#container2 {
  width: 48%;
}

.legend {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.legend__item {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.legend__dot {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.legend__dot--black {
  background-color: black;
}

.legend__dot--blue {
  background-color: #7BB5EC;
}

.legend__item--disabled .legend__dot {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.legend__item--disabled .legend__caption {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="container1"></div>
  <div id="container2"></div>
</div>

<div class="legend">
  <div class="legend__item jsLegendItem" data-name="series1">
    <span class="legend__dot legend__dot--blue"></span>
    <span class="legend__caption">Series 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="legend__item jsLegendItem" data-name="series2">
    <span class="legend__dot legend__dot--black"></span>
    <span class="legend__caption">Series 2</span>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Download</button>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/czwut6n5/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#show
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#hide